# After Upgrading to 22.04 Internet access not working

Tags: xubuntu

I started Upgrading Ubuntu from 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS. After Upgrading I can't use internet access. any reach outs, please

Comment: Maybe you can narrow down a bit what "can't use internet access" means. Have you tried `ping askubuntu.com`? What does it give you? Maybe try with `ping 151.101.65.69` to see if that is the same problem. Check whether you have a connection at all `ifconfig -a`, etc.

Comment: Maybe the comments in this question https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406208/wifi-not-working-after-upgrading-to-22-04 can help you narrow down the problem, especially the hint to https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos