# WiFi not working after upgrading to 22.04

Tags: wireless, iwlwifi, 22.04, firmware

I upgraded to version 22.04 some days ago, and from that day I have been fighting with the WiFi, but could not make it work. The fact is the card is present, but it is not recognized by the system. The output of lspci shows all the card details:

```
(base) luis@Carmen-HP:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 61)
    DeviceName: Intel Dual BandWireless-AC 7265 802.11 ac 1x1 WiFi + BT 4.0 Combo Adapter
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5010]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

But in the configuration menus the WiFi appears as "Not Available". I have tried several ways to update the package "backport-iwlwifi-dkms" and the /lib/firmware folder contents, the last one as described in the answer here:

[Wireless Network not showing with iwlwifi card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1401173/wireless-network-not-showing-with-iwlwifi-card)

But nothing seems to change anything. I have also tried adding some options to the /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf file, as described here (sorry the link is in Spanish):

https://slimbook.es/en/tutoriales/linux/79-configurando-driver-wifi-intel-iwlwifi-conf

as, even though my laptop is not a Slimbook, the chip is the same and it was an easy test. But nothing changed.

The output of dmesg is the following:

```
(base) luis@Carmen-HP:~$ sudo dmesg | grep iw
[    5.230910] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
[    5.230913] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:9858:4c7cba27
[    5.285225] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    5.285240] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[    5.285501] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.f2390aa8.0 7265D-29.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    5.419606] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
[    5.434004] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    5.434396] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    5.442498] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: base HW address: c8:21:58:59:b0:5f, OTP minor version: 0x0
[    5.505126] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    8.458692] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    8.537179] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    8.538492] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[    8.559211] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: mac start retry 0
[    8.573295] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    8.651234] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    8.652397] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[    8.675001] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: mac start retry 1
[    8.689462] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    8.775924] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    8.777199] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[    8.799885] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: mac start retry 2
[    8.824928] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    8.902466] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    8.903805] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[    8.929417] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: mac start retry 0
[    8.943419] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    9.029111] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    9.030368] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[    9.052862] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: mac start retry 1
[    9.066967] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    9.153272] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    9.154832] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[    9.181093] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: mac start retry 2
[    9.211600] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    9.296095] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    9.297506] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[    9.321403] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: mac start retry 0
[    9.335573] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    9.421158] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    9.422423] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[    9.445741] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: mac start retry 1
[    9.459838] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    9.547492] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    9.548780] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[    9.573399] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: mac start retry 2
[   20.022804] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   20.101774] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   20.102986] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[   20.126480] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: mac start retry 0
[   20.140345] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   20.220178] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   20.221749] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[   20.243784] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: mac start retry 1
[   20.257398] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   20.336429] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   20.337671] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[   20.359611] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: mac start retry 2
[   20.376628] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   20.464329] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   20.465835] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[   20.489444] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: mac start retry 0
[   20.503511] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   20.582267] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   20.584052] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[   20.611604] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: mac start retry 1
[   20.625064] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   20.704483] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   20.706069] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[   20.735718] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: mac start retry 2
[   31.021083] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   31.107791] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   31.109129] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[   31.131563] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: mac start retry 0
[   31.145200] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   31.231600] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   31.233177] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[   31.257412] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: mac start retry 1
[   31.271697] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   31.357149] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   31.358712] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[   31.383568] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: mac start retry 2
[   31.397327] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   31.484263] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   31.485594] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[   31.509367] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: mac start retry 0
[   31.524566] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   31.611024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   31.612252] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[   31.635024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: mac start retry 1
[   31.649196] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   31.735292] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   31.736533] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[   31.759668] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: mac start retry 2
[   41.884078] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   41.965962] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   41.967469] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[   42.001831] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: mac start retry 0
[   42.016263] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   42.097977] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   42.099382] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[   42.131282] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: mac start retry 1
[   42.145201] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   42.226990] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   42.228827] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[   42.263716] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: mac start retry 2
[   42.278697] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   42.359041] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   42.360471] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[   42.386558] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: mac start retry 0
[   42.403035] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   42.484093] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   42.485660] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[   42.521341] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: mac start retry 1
[   42.536160] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   42.616209] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   42.617685] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[   42.650936] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: mac start retry 2
[   52.728662] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   52.810365] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   52.811919] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[   52.840683] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: mac start retry 0
[   52.855481] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   52.944260] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   52.945697] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[   52.974703] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: mac start retry 1
[   52.990432] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   53.070736] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   53.072130] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[   53.105183] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: mac start retry 2
[   53.121337] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   53.202808] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   53.204214] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[   53.233562] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: mac start retry 0
[   53.247610] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   53.327163] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   53.328602] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[   53.357672] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: mac start retry 1
[   53.372481] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   53.453976] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   53.455322] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[   53.485314] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: mac start retry 2
[   63.691942] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   63.773512] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   63.774947] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[   63.811529] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: mac start retry 0
[   63.827229] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   63.909318] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   63.910867] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[   63.945272] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: mac start retry 1
[   63.959628] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   64.040623] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   64.042171] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[   64.077989] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: mac start retry 2
[   64.093029] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   64.173908] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   64.175460] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[   64.208745] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: mac start retry 0
[   64.224300] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   64.314272] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   64.316293] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[   64.350263] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: mac start retry 1
[   64.364806] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   64.446103] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   64.447607] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[   64.482126] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: mac start retry 2
```

And nothing seems to be blocked, either by hw or sw:

```
(base) luis@Carmen-HP:~$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I am a bit out of ideas at this point. Any suggestions on how to grab more information or what to try to get back my wifi??

Comment: I would be very surprised to find that you actually needed backport. I suggest that you do: `sudo apt purge backport-iwlwifi-dkms` Reboot and show us a new version of: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: @chili555, you are absolutely right. Purging the package did the trick and I am now answering from my wifi. I will now have to study what is the exact purpose of that package and why it made my WiFi unrecognizable. Thanks!!

Comment: @rodrigo-aguado have you found out why you had backport-iwlwifi-dkms installed on you laptop? It was also the root cause of my issue (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1416493/how-to-enable-ethernet-interface-ubuntu-22-04-solved)

Comment: The comment from chili555 was the solution for me, having the same problem. It might be flagged as the solution here.

Answer (score 1):

> I would be very surprised to find that you actually needed backport. I suggest that you do:
>
> ```
> sudo apt purge backport-iwlwifi-dkms
> ```
>
> Then reboot.

<sup>Answer moved here (slightly modified) from [chili555's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406208/wifi-not-working-after-upgrading-to-22-04#comment2442368_1406208).</sup>