# Wifi issue - 20.04 LTS vs Centrino Advanced N 6205

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, iwlwifi, centrino

I am encountering lot of drop outs and instability (constant drop out) with my Wifi on Lenovo x230 with card

```
Centrino Advanced-N 6205 Taylor Peak
Physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
logical name: wlp3s0
version:34
width: 64
clock: 33Mhz
```

Anything I tried to do, did not seem to resolve the issue. Please anybody has an idea about fixing it - driver update or something similar.
I love my Linux, but I am pretty much noob.

Thank you very much in advance.
Tomas

```
CPU: i73615 QE@2.30GHz - 8 core
Gnome: 3.36.8
Windowing: x11 product: Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 34
       serial: a4:4e:31:2a:7a:f8
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.13.0-41-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 6000g2a-6.ucode latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:30 memory:f1400000-f1401fff
```

Comment: *what* have you tried to do? Please do list it in detail. It would make no sense for us to start listing things you've tried already.

Comment: also please run the script in the first answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos), which will give us the information we need to help with wifi issues

Comment: also, try running `sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off` (sub `wlan0` for your wireless interface if it's different). This will turn off power management for your wifi card, so it won't sleep when it isn't busy. However, if your problem is caused by the card "power managing" when it shouldn't, this will fix it. To make this permanent (if it works), follow the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85214/how-can-i-prevent-iwconfig-power-management-from-being-turned-on).

Comment: It may be related to your neighbors networks, or a hardware issue (detached antenna). It can't be fixed on OS level.

Comment: do you have bluetooth enabled? because there is a [kernel bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=97101) registered about this issue, specifically when bluetooth is enabled.

Comment: I have the wifi and bluetooth hardward for this bug, and use it without issue, on 11n.  From the /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf file, I'm using the iwldvm firmware, not the iwlmvm.

Comment: I tried to update driver - to no avail.

Comment: I tried to disable powersave on wlan, but sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
[sudo] password for tomas: 
Error for wireless request "Set Power Management" (8B2C) :
    SET failed on device wlan0 ; No such device.
tomas@Sirius:~$ sudo iwconfig wlan power off
Error for wireless request "Set Power Management" (8B2C) :
    SET failed on device wlan ; No such device.

Comment: @Pilot6 I am not sure about the neighbouring network, but do you have somewhere the service manual, so I can actually open and check? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can install wi-fi diagnostic tool to your phone and see what is around you.

Comment: @Pilot6 I lot and there is always a plenty around me. Funny part is, that when I share net over phone it tends to be stable. Computer had been overhauled - I have a custom screen, speakers and new motherboard. (Full HD on Lenovo x230, so I have a Chinese mod soldered to motherboard). I need to get tools to open computer and look for antena problem. I ran the script again - but bloody hell I have no idea what you mean by result. I got the file in txt / gz format, but what is the info I should post.

Comment: You need to post contents of `wireless-info.txt` file.

Comment: @Pilot6 this caught my attention, as there is no apparent reason (for me) to timeout: wlp3s0: deauthenticated from <MAC 'Jurassic Park' [AC8]> (Reason: 15=4WAY_HANDSHAKE_TIMEOUT)

Comment: I can not add pictures neither add file. I am a new user.... the whole thing has a over 30 000 signs so that does not allow me to do anything either.

Comment: Is it actually possible, that upgrading to 22.04 would solve the issue Wifi (if it is not a mechanical one)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt remove backport-iwlwifi-dkms
```

resolved this problem caused by the dist-upgrade to 22.04 on ThinkPad T430.

- [WiFi not working after upgrading to 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406208/wifi-not-working-after-upgrading-to-22-04)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1247122)

Answer (score -2):

I just found that there is a [kernel bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=97101) registered about this issue, specifically when bluetooth is enabled.

A possible solution is to put the following line:

```
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

in the file

```
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

However, this can affect your internet speed or possibly something else, depending on how your router is configured. But if your issues are caused by this bug, they may be much improved by this configuration.

Comment: This is a very old bug, it obsolete for a long time. And the solution are not good at all.

Comment: As the bug report says, the 6205 chipset does not have bluetooth

Comment: @Pilot6 ok. Thanks for teaching me.