# How to enable Ethernet Interface (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: networking, wireless, intel

Laptop: HP Spectre X360  15-bl001na

Ubuntu 22.04 does not see any wifi network, then I checked with the command below and I see a "DISABLED".

How can I enable that interface?

```
$ sudo lshw -class network
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3b:00.0
       logical name: wlp59s0
       version: 78
       serial: 00:28:f8:3d:dd:58
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.15.0-40-generic firmware=36.ca7b901d.0 8265-36.ucode latency=0 link=no multicast=yes
       resources: irq:149 memory:dd300000-dd301fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 11
       bus info: usb@4:1
       logical name: enx00e04c689b6e
       serial: 00:e0:4c:68:9b:6e
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.12.12 duplex=full firmware=rtl8153a-4 v2 02/07/20 ip=192.168.10.112 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
```

And the results of `sudo ifconfig eth0 up` and `ifconfig -a`:

```
$ sudo ifconfig eth0 up
eth0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device

$ ifconfig -a
enx00e04c689b6e: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.10.112  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.10.255
        inet6 fdee:569e:153:1:26c:b654:dd91:80a6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::bc95:8997:9cc1:46d9  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fdee:569e:153:1:cc97:9d2b:2679:afc5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 00:e0:4c:68:9b:6e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 8360  bytes 6322125 (6.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5815  bytes 986862 (986.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 889  bytes 87942 (87.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 889  bytes 87942 (87.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp59s0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:28:f8:3d:dd:58  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

and the result for `frkill` is:

```
$ rfkill list all
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

and this is the content of `/etc/network/interfaces` is:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

I can also add that, in the Ubuntu config panel, WiFi is of course enabled but the "Visible networks" is spinning forever
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ir4FQ.png)

Adding also info about iwlwifi module:

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep iwl
[    5.807156] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
[    5.807160] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:9858:4c7cba27
[    5.931364] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    5.945970] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: loaded firmware version 36.ca7b901d.0 8265-36.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    6.040276] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8265, REV=0x230
[    6.111727] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: base HW address: 00:28:f8:3d:dd:58, OTP minor version: 0x0
[    6.187327] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    6.939593] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0 wlp59s0: renamed from wlan0
[    8.244186] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: mac start retry 0
[    8.491711] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: mac start retry 1
[    8.734390] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: mac start retry 2
[    8.997580] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: mac start retry 0
[    9.246283] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: mac start retry 1
[    9.485438] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: mac start retry 2
[    9.734349] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: mac start retry 0
[    9.970349] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: mac start retry 1
...
```

Comment: Have you tried `$ sudo ifconfig eth0 up`? "eth0" is the name of your ethernet connection your want to activate, and may be something different on your system. You can also use the same command to activate wifi. If you run `$ ifconfig -a` you get a list of all interfaces and their status.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, please check my revised question..

Comment: The problem is elsewhere, I think. I can't offer you any help on that.

Comment: @Lorenzo Best to place any requested command line output *appended* to your question rather than placed as a new answer. I have sorted it out...

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `rfkill list all` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi @chili555 many thanks for your help and suggestion about how to manage my request. I'll do, from now on, as you recommended. 
I'm adding the result for rfkill command

Comment: could you please also recommend a better title for my question? I find my title quite generic, but don't know how to technically improve it.

Comment: The name of your disabled device isn't `eth0` it's `wlp59s0`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WiFi not working after upgrading to 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406208/wifi-not-working-after-upgrading-to-22-04)

Answer (score 3):

Same issue.  Figured out that I had moved around some hardware, specifically an LSI disk controller.
This seemingly unrelated benign act caused my network card address to change!

To resolve just edit the auto generated netplan file

```
sudo  /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
```

```
cat  /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml

# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enp6s0:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

any number of tools including `ifconfig`, `ip a`, etc. will show you what the correct interface id is.   In my example the interface ID had changed from enp5s0 to enp6s0.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This isn't related in the very slightest to the original question.

Comment:  it is related, BECAUSE "same issue" .. the scenario as described caused the same error message and google led me to this page.

Comment: This is absolutely related. If the ethernet port was working, some hardware additions change the address of the port, effectively disabling it. I had exactly the same problem from adding an SSD drive.