# Ubuntu 22.04 Network doesn't work until NetworkManager restarted

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, 22.04, ethernet

Following upgrading from 20.04 to 22.04, networking doesn't work until I issue

`sudo nmcli networking off && sudo nmcli networking on`

This is true of both ethernet/wired and wifi and ping from the terminal. I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 on a Lenovo X230 laptop.

Perhaps relevant: when using Ubuntu 20.04 networking would work on boot but when I swapped from wired to wifi or vice versa, I needed to restart NetworkManager with the above command. Under 22.04 networking doesn't work on boot until it's restarted and I need to restart when switching.

I could hack it by adding it to login but I'm sure it'll bite me later if I don't find the root cause.

Here's the result of `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager` after boot when networking isn't working. This is using a wired connection with wifi turned off, confirmed by sw rfkill:

```
Aug 23 11:13:19 lenovo-x230u systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
Aug 23 11:13:19 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249599.3132] NetworkManager (version 1.36.6) is starting... (for the first time)
Aug 23 11:13:19 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249599.3139] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 10-dns-resolved.conf, 20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf, no-mac-addr-change.conf) (run: 10-globally-managed-devices.conf) (etc: default-wifi-powersave-on.conf, wgpia.conf)
Aug 23 11:13:19 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249599.3384] bus-manager: acquired D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
Aug 23 11:13:19 lenovo-x230u systemd[1]: Started Network Manager.
Aug 23 11:13:19 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249599.3524] manager[0x556e30144030]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
Aug 23 11:13:19 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249599.3525] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/network/ifstate'.
Aug 23 11:13:20 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249600.1036] hostname: hostname: using hostnamed
Aug 23 11:13:20 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249600.1036] hostname: static hostname changed from (none) to "lenovo-x230u"
Aug 23 11:13:20 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249600.1081] dns-mgr[0x556e3011e2a0]: init: dns=systemd-resolved rc-manager=unmanaged (auto), plugin=systemd-resolved
Aug 23 11:13:20 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249600.1107] rfkill2: found Wi-Fi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:03:00.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill2) (driver iwlwifi)
Aug 23 11:13:20 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249600.1111] rfkill1: found WWAN radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/rfkill/rfkill1) (platform driver thinkpad_acpi)
Aug 23 11:13:20 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249600.1170] manager[0x556e30144030]: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardware radio set disabled
Aug 23 11:13:20 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249600.1192] manager[0x556e30144030]: rfkill: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
Aug 23 11:13:20 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249600.1292] Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-team.so)
Aug 23 11:13:20 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249600.1364] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
Aug 23 11:13:20 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249600.1373] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-wwan.so)
Aug 23 11:13:20 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249600.1393] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-wifi.so)
Aug 23 11:13:20 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249600.1414] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-adsl.so)
Aug 23 11:13:20 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249600.1419] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi enabled by radio killswitch; disabled by state file
Aug 23 11:13:20 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249600.1421] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Aug 23 11:13:20 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249600.1423] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
Aug 23 11:13:20 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249600.1510] settings: Loaded settings plugin: ifupdown ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-settings-plugin-ifupdown.so")
Aug 23 11:13:20 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249600.1511] settings: Loaded settings plugin: keyfile (internal)
Aug 23 11:13:20 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249600.1511] ifupdown: management mode: managed
Aug 23 11:13:20 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249600.1512] ifupdown:       interface-parser: parsing file /etc/network/interfaces
Aug 23 11:13:20 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249600.1512] ifupdown:       interface-parser: finished parsing file /etc/network/interfaces
Aug 23 11:13:20 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249600.1718] dhcp-init: Using DHCP client 'internal'
Aug 23 11:13:20 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249600.1719] device (lo): carrier: link connected
Aug 23 11:13:20 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249600.1723] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
Aug 23 11:13:20 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249600.1747] manager: (enp0s25): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
Aug 23 11:13:20 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249600.1784] device (enp0s25): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug 23 11:13:20 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249600.4234] device (wlp3s0): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
Aug 23 11:13:20 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249600.4245] manager: (wlp3s0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
Aug 23 11:13:20 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249600.4273] device (wlp3s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug 23 11:13:20 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249600.4338] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi now disabled by radio killswitch
Aug 23 11:13:20 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249600.4612] modem-manager: ModemManager available
Aug 23 11:13:20 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249600.6117] manager: (D0:3F:AA:1D:31:62): new Bluetooth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4)
Aug 23 11:13:20 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249600.6154] device (D0:3F:AA:1D:31:62): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug 23 11:13:20 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249600.6208] device (D0:3F:AA:1D:31:62): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 23 11:13:23 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249603.9315] device (enp0s25): carrier: link connected
Aug 23 11:13:23 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249603.9323] device (enp0s25): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 23 11:13:23 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249603.9342] policy: auto-activating connection 'Wired connection 1' (83d94562-7e3b-3ed8-a967-ecbb1533efd1)
Aug 23 11:13:23 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249603.9355] device (enp0s25): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 1' (83d94562-7e3b-3ed8-a967-ecbb1533efd1)
Aug 23 11:13:23 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249603.9358] device (enp0s25): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 23 11:13:23 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249603.9367] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Aug 23 11:13:23 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249603.9372] device (enp0s25): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 23 11:13:23 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249603.9392] device (enp0s25): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 23 11:13:23 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249603.9405] dhcp4 (enp0s25): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Aug 23 11:13:30 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249610.0654] dhcp4 (enp0s25): state changed new lease, address=109.41.187.122
Aug 23 11:13:30 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249610.0697] device (enp0s25): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 23 11:13:30 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249610.0748] device (enp0s25): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 23 11:13:30 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249610.0752] device (enp0s25): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 23 11:13:30 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249610.0757] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Aug 23 11:13:30 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249610.0763] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Aug 23 11:13:30 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249610.0764] policy: set 'Wired connection 1' (enp0s25) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Aug 23 11:13:30 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249610.0775] device (enp0s25): Activation: successful, device activated.
Aug 23 11:13:30 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249610.0783] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Aug 23 11:13:30 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249610.0792] manager: startup complete
Aug 23 11:13:31 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249611.5250] manager: (tun0): new Tun device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/5)
Aug 23 11:13:31 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249611.5372] device (tun0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug 23 11:13:31 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249611.5379] device (tun0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug 23 11:13:31 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249611.5387] device (tun0): Activation: starting connection 'tun0' (701076b1-8a64-43a5-afbe-e8f74c5d1988)
Aug 23 11:13:31 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249611.5389] device (tun0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug 23 11:13:31 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249611.5392] device (tun0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug 23 11:13:31 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249611.5394] device (tun0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug 23 11:13:31 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249611.5397] device (tun0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug 23 11:13:31 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249611.5450] device (tun0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug 23 11:13:31 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249611.5453] device (tun0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug 23 11:13:31 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249611.5459] device (tun0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Aug 23 11:13:31 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249611.5806] device (tun0): state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'unmanaged', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
Aug 23 11:13:32 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249612.7841] agent-manager: agent[4b5f25c2c3ee9b06,:1.66/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/120]: agent registered
Aug 23 11:13:42 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249622.1267] manager: (cdc-wdm2): new Broadband device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/6)
Aug 23 11:13:42 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249622.1269] device (cdc-wdm2): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug 23 11:13:42 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249622.1272] device (cdc-wdm2): modem state 'failed'
Aug 23 11:13:42 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249622.1274] modem-broadband[cdc-wdm2]: failed to retrieve SIM object: No SIM object available
Aug 23 11:13:43 lenovo-x230u NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661249623.6756] agent-manager: agent[f9c25a7fcc12b782,:1.105/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered
```

And here's what gets added to journalctl when restarted and networking works:

```
Aug 23 11:21:04 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250064.1751] manager: disable requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Aug 23 11:21:04 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250064.1751] device (wlp3s0): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 23 11:21:04 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250064.1761] device (D0:3F:AA:1D:31:62): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 23 11:21:04 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250064.1765] device (cdc-wdm2): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 23 11:21:04 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250064.1768] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Aug 23 11:21:04 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250064.1772] audit: op="networking-control" arg="off" pid=3691 uid=0 result="success"
Aug 23 11:21:04 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250064.1772] device (enp0s25): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 23 11:21:04 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250064.2051] device (enp0s25): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 23 11:21:04 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250064.2290] dhcp4 (enp0s25): canceled DHCP transaction
Aug 23 11:21:04 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250064.2290] dhcp4 (enp0s25): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Aug 23 11:21:04 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250064.2291] dhcp4 (enp0s25): state changed no lease
Aug 23 11:21:04 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250064.2605] device (enp0s25): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 23 11:21:04 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250064.3726] manager: enable requested (sleeping: no  enabled: no)
Aug 23 11:21:04 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250064.3726] device (enp0s25): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug 23 11:21:04 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250064.5898] device (wlp3s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug 23 11:21:04 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250064.5913] device (D0:3F:AA:1D:31:62): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug 23 11:21:04 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250064.5919] device (cdc-wdm2): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug 23 11:21:04 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250064.5922] device (cdc-wdm2): modem state 'failed'
Aug 23 11:21:04 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250064.5922] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Aug 23 11:21:04 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250064.5925] audit: op="networking-control" arg="on" pid=3701 uid=0 result="success"
Aug 23 11:21:04 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250064.5927] device (D0:3F:AA:1D:31:62): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 23 11:21:07 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250067.9398] device (enp0s25): carrier: link connected
Aug 23 11:21:07 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250067.9401] device (enp0s25): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 23 11:21:07 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250067.9412] policy: auto-activating connection 'Wired connection 1' (83d94562-7e3b-3ed8-a967-ecbb1533efd1)
Aug 23 11:21:07 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250067.9417] device (enp0s25): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 1' (83d94562-7e3b-3ed8-a967-ecbb1533efd1)
Aug 23 11:21:07 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250067.9418] device (enp0s25): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 23 11:21:07 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250067.9421] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Aug 23 11:21:07 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250067.9423] device (enp0s25): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 23 11:21:07 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250067.9427] device (enp0s25): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 23 11:21:07 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250067.9446] dhcp4 (enp0s25): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Aug 23 11:21:13 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250073.3108] dhcp4 (enp0s25): state changed new lease, address=109.41.187.122
Aug 23 11:21:13 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250073.3141] device (enp0s25): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 23 11:21:13 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250073.3180] device (enp0s25): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 23 11:21:13 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250073.3182] device (enp0s25): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 23 11:21:13 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250073.3186] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Aug 23 11:21:13 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250073.3190] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Aug 23 11:21:13 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250073.3191] policy: set 'Wired connection 1' (enp0s25) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Aug 23 11:21:13 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250073.3198] device (enp0s25): Activation: successful, device activated.
Aug 23 11:21:13 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250073.3202] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Aug 23 11:21:19 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250079.5315] manager: (tun0): new Tun device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/7)
Aug 23 11:21:19 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250079.5457] device (tun0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug 23 11:21:19 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250079.5463] device (tun0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug 23 11:21:19 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250079.5472] device (tun0): Activation: starting connection 'tun0' (636e9827-baab-4be7-a7c2-5a85705cb915)
Aug 23 11:21:19 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250079.5474] device (tun0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug 23 11:21:19 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250079.5477] device (tun0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug 23 11:21:19 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250079.5479] device (tun0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug 23 11:21:19 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250079.5482] device (tun0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug 23 11:21:19 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250079.5573] device (tun0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug 23 11:21:19 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250079.5575] device (tun0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug 23 11:21:19 lenovo-x230uu NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1661250079.5582] device (tun0): Activation: successful, device activated.
```

I can't see the reason for one working and the other not.

When it's not working `ping www.google.com` results in `ping: www.google.com: Name or service not known`

`/etc/network/interfaces` contains

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

`/etc/network/interfaces.d` is empty

When working output from `sudo ifconfig enp0s25` is

```
enp0s25: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.122  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::d674:d367:b557:214  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 3c:97:0e:ce:42:5f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 7241  bytes 4999361 (4.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6657  bytes 1431722 (1.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xf1500000-f1520000
```

And when not working (previously been working hence packet count):

```
enp0s25: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.122  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::d674:d367:b557:214  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 3c:97:0e:ce:42:5f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 37277  bytes 34292203 (34.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 2  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 25441  bytes 6275182 (6.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xf1500000-f1520000
```

`uname -a` gives

```
Linux lenevo-x230u 5.15.0-46-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 4 18:03:25 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`rfkill list all` gives

```
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: tpacpi_wwan_sw: Wireless WAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

The yes for wifi is expected as I'm currently testing with wired. If I switch wifi back on, rfkill behaves as expected and network issue remains.

I'm using kernel 5.15.0-46 so it's not [this issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403954/wifi-issues-in-ubuntu-22-04lts)

Package backport-iwlwifi-dkms isn't installed so its not [this issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406208/wifi-not-working-after-upgrading-to-22-04)

Any help much appreciated

Comment: As per the link in @dothello's comment I tried

`sudo nmcli networking on`

figuring it couldn't hurt. It hasn't changed the behaviour.

Additional info:
`sudo nmcli networking connectivity check`
results in "full" even when the networking isn't working

A quick check of the logs shows when the connection drops, the IP address changes. It may indicate the issue is not netplan on this machine but the network.

I've found it was set to a fixed IP that was on the wrong subnet (192.168.0 instead of 192.168.1) although that wasn't the IP assigned. Now corrected. Let's see if resolved.

Comment: It hasn't changed behaviour. Network Manager still needs to restart to establish connection at boot and when switching from wired to wireless. Also when roaming between wifi APs.

Note the IP address changes when moving from wired to wireless connection (as you would expect) which seems to cause NM to need to be restarted to re-establish network connection

Comment: There is no /etc/network/interfaces or /etc/network/interfaces.d in Ubuntu 22.04. I only have a /etc/network directory because I had to install the net-tools package for the "ifconfig" related commands. Every major release makes it harder to manage networks.

Answer (score 4):

For me the issue seemed to be the VPN kill switch. I use Proton VPN.

Comment: Since the OP makes no mention of a VPN in the question fail to see how this is an answer.

Comment: There are various VPNs set up on the laptop in question for access to corporate networks but the issues occurs both when a VPN is being used or not

Comment: This answer actually solved my issue. I did:  `protonvpn-cli ks --off`

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same issue, and restarting nmcli as you suggested is the only way I could make it work again. No idea why.
Edit: [Reports of problems after an update](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/wmowxl/problems_with_ubuntu_22041/) (My network options were not showing either)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

i had exactly same  output on terminal and symtomps. I had to reboot my modem +--+-> Router ----Ethernt to my PC_ubuntu. It worked, right away, after wasting my 4 hours of troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue, perhaps the same, on a Lenovo X280 with Ubuntu 22.04.2. The wifi wouldn't work when I boot the laptop. The OP's work around solution worked for me. The following from `/var/log/syslog` maybe useful in figuring this out.

```
Mar 18 08:20:31 laptop NetworkManager[904]: <info>  [1679127631.1105] device (wlp59s0): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
Mar 18 08:20:31 laptop NetworkManager[904]: <info>  [1679127631.1116] manager: (wlp59s0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
Mar 18 08:20:31 laptop NetworkManager[904]: <info>  [1679127631.1119] device (wlp59s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Mar 18 08:20:31 laptop NetworkManager[904]: <info>  [1679127631.1133] failed to open /run/network/ifstate
Mar 18 08:20:31 laptop NetworkManager[904]: <info>  [1679127631.1195] modem-manager: ModemManager available
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1287779)