# No wifi after clean install of Ubuntu 22.04.02 on newly refurbished computer

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 22.04, intel

I have a newly refurbished HP laptop:

HP HP ZBook 14u G5
Intel® Core™ i7-8650U CPU @ 1.90GHz × 8
AMD® Radeon pro wx 3100 / Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)

I did a clean install of Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, with kernel version: 5.19.0-42-generic

And I discover that the computer does not see the wifi adapter. Here is the result of doing `lshw – C network`:

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 78
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:ba200000-ba201fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (4) I219-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 21
       serial: b4:b6:86:8e:d8:17
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.19.0-42-generic firmware=0.1-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:127 memory:ba400000-ba41ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: e
       bus info: usb@1:2
       logical name: enx025263346633
       serial: 02:52:63:34:66:33
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=5.19.0-42-generic duplex=half firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.239 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

I updated and upgraded Ubuntu, and then followed the instructions on this page to install the intel driver (iwlwifi-8265-22.ucode):

https://www.linuxfordevices.com/tutorials/ubuntu/no-wi-fi-adapter-found-error

Still doesn’t work.

(New edit to my question). I found a question on Ask Ubuntu that looked like mine, involving the same intel wifi firmware:

([WiFi not working after upgrading to 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406208/wifi-not-working-after-upgrading-to-22-04))

In this person's case purging the backports solved the problem. In my case, the backports are not on the computer:

```
sudo apt purge backport-iwlwifi-dkms  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree... Done  
Reading state information... Done  
Package 'backport-iwlwifi-dkms' is not installed, so not removed  
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded
```

Could this be the problem? Also what is a backport?

When I do `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`

I get the following message:

```
[    3.033851] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)  
[    3.754261] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:02:00.0 failed with error -110
```

Finally, per comment below, here is the the output from `rfkill list all`

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth  
    Soft blocked: no  
    Hard blocked: no
```

The output from `lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network` is

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:24fd] (rev 78)  
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265 [8086:0010]  
Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-  
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-  
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 19  
Region 0: Memory at ba200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]  
Capabilities: <access denied>  
Kernel modules: iwlwifi  
3c:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983 [144d:a808] (prog-if 02 [NVM Express])
```

I have read through multiple different sites now and I see that there are apparently a lot of network connectivity issues with Ubuntu 22. I would not describe myself as a superuser, but I’ve been using earlier versions of Ubuntu for years, and never encountered problems like this. Also, I know that the wifi adapter works, because the computer originally came with Windows 10 and the wifi worked without a problem (This is how I downloaded the ISO for Ubuntu). Also just to confirm from the discussion in the comments, airplane mode is off.

Can anyone provide some help here?

Comment: That page provides a solution for a Realtek wireless cad, which you don't have. Is there a harware switch that's off?

Comment: Thanks! If you scroll down on the site, it provides instructions on how to download and then install the necessary intel driver. It's the last example on the site. As for your other question, you'll have to excuse my ignorance but what is a hardware (?) switch, and how would I check if it is off?

Comment: Thanks for the information. There is no hardware switch. The wifi did work without any problem when Windows 10 was still on the computer (i.e. last night), but I didn't partition the drive and only have Ubuntu on the computer now.

Comment: Ah yes, but in case of Intel, it is not the driver but firmware, which is already present in Ubuntu, so that you didn't need to download and install it. Hardware switch is a phisical button or knob, usually made of plastic or metal. that one can push with a finger. The computer actually sees "the wifi adapter", otherwise, how would you know what to download? ...but the module isn't loaded, so it doesn't work..

Comment: That is odd, how about the top row, 6-th buttong from the right?

Comment: Airplane mode? I can confirm that airplane mode has been off during all of this. Thanks. Also, I added more information above now, as I found a similar issue in Ask Ubuntu, though their solution did not work for me.

Comment: So, [Ubuntu backports](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports) is a special repository. It is not enabled by default, but you might want to add the output of `rfkill list all` as well.

Comment: Did you see any drivers for WiFi in the additional drivers tab in `Software & Sources`?

Comment: In software and updates on the additional drivers tabs, it says "No additional drivers available" It also says "no proprietary drivers are in use."

Comment: My problem has resolved but I'm not sure what happened. I tried other distros (Mint, POP OS, Ubuntu 23.04), and the wifi didn't work in any of them. However, after installing Ubuntu 23.04, I went into the BIOS settings. There I went into the wifi settings. I DID NOT CHANGE ANYTHING, but I toggled one setting on/off. I actually did not change the setting in the end, because I thought I should not be messing around with settings I do not understand. However, when I emerged from BIOS and started using the computer, the wifi magically started working.

Answer (score 1):

As [@Kuns said in his last comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1469653/no-wifi-after-clean-install-of-ubuntu-22-04-02-on-newly-refurbished-computer/1502477#comment2577515_1469653), turning my Wi-Fi off and on in the BIOS did the trick for me too on my DELL Latitude 5490 - a completely different device. I thought it was a tad ridiculous, but hell, what did I have to lose.

I first turned everything Wi-Fi related off, then saved the settings. Then I turned everything Wi-Fi related back on, saved the settings again, and after a reboot, lo and behold, my Wi-Fi was working too. Beyond bewildered this actually worked, thanks a bunch!